# Send email from Heroku server using gmail account and PHPMailer

Tags: email-server, spam, heroku

I have a Heroku app which has a php script that send out an email. The email sent always goes to spam.

Let's say the heroku app is mywebsite.herokuapp.com and my email is mywebsite@gmail.com. Based on my research I understand that the problem might be that the email is being sent from my server which is mywebsite.herokuapp.com but the email address is gmail.com.

If I used `$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';` can this be the problem?

Based on my research other problems might be with the SPF or the DKIM

I spent a ton of hours trying to look it up online but everything I found had to do with custom domains and their DNS settings (for a start) which you can't have with a Heroku app.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/1040690/how-do-i-send-emails-from-a-different-domain) was the closest that I got to helpful information but it didn't give me enough information to go on.

Comment: Have you own site name? In example myapp.com or only mywebsite.herokuapp.com?

Comment: Only mywebsite.herokuapp.com

Comment: Depending on how much mail and what type of mail goes through Gmail, you may get your Gmail account suspended or cancelled as a violation of their ToS.

Comment: i just sent a couple of test emails to a different email of mine...

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail thru gmail but getting it going is a process. You'll have to generate an app userid/pass and then do the setup steps for your system's MTA (i.e. Postfix/sendmail).
I've done this myself several times and it works well.
There are sending limits however, even if you have a paid gmail account (i.e. Google for Business).

The source! Google itself says to do it this way: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en

and one from other users on serverfault: [Configure Postfix to send/relay emails Gmail (smtp.gmail.com) via port 587](https://serverfault.com/questions/119278/configure-postfix-to-send-relay-emails-gmail-smtp-gmail-com-via-port-587)

You can also use services like SendGrid and MailChimp but they'll also want money. Free gmail accounts can do this however the sending limits are much lower.

Comment: But what if I have the email proccess going, meaning the emails send but if I send it to someone this way it goes to spam automatically until the user marks it as non spam?

Comment: Using DKIM and SPF in conjunction with a commercial mail relay service should keep your mail out of user SPAM folders unless your mails get flagged for something else typical of UCE.